# Should sublimetext and sublimetext2 be synonyms?

Tags: support, synonym-request

[sublimetext](/questions/tagged/sublimetext), [sublimetext2](/questions/tagged/sublimetext2) and [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3) should be synonyms. It's not helpful to have separate tags for various versions of the same app when there's so little difference between versions. It's also not clear whether the first tag means 'all versions' or 'version 1'

Comment: IMO [tag:sublimetext] should refer to both 1 and 2, since everybody uses 2 and [tag:sublimetext3] should remain distinct

Comment: Insert slippery slope wrt version-specific tags here, including but not limited to breaking out the old example of `php5` (current version, aliased to `php` currently) vs `php4` (old version) vs `php` and what happens when the next version is released.